# How to get Herobrine skin and powers (invisibility)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I get Herobrine's appearance WITH his powers? I had recently watched a video where the person turned into Herobrine and had his powers to fly and become invisible. How do I do that? If it's a mod, please put a link.

Comment: that was faked, there is no herobrine in minecraft, the powers were done with potions and creative mode

Answer (score 7):

You can get herobrine skin [here](http://www.minecraftskins.net/herobrine).

The abilities you said does not require mod to do so, but permissions.

Use `/gamemode <player> creative` to turn a player into creative mode, which grants abilities to obtain/destroy any blocks and fly. This command requires operator permission to use.

`/vanish` is the command which makes yourself invisible. This command requires bukkit-based server and the permission is `vanish.vanish`.

Comment: Or you could use the invisibility potion effect...

Comment: Yes, but you cannot control when to appear precisely.

Comment: Yes you can.  You can clear an invisibility potion effect by using `/effect @p 14 0` (14 is the invisibility ID).  Not only that, you can set it to not show particles with the command line, something you can't do with an actual potion.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you mean the potion only.

Comment: Because you said "Invisibility Potion Effect", I assumed you were talking about the potion only.

Comment: If I was talking just about potions, I would have said "invisibility potions'.

Comment: Yeah this is certainly my mistake.

Comment: @008 Drinking Milk also clears all effects I believe

Comment: (1.13 syntax for command: `/effect clear @p minecraft:invisibility`)

Answer (score 0):

You could find/make the skin and you cold drink a potion of invisibility for the invisible part and you could use commands/mods to fly.

If you want to make it (the skin) you can go to "http://www.minecraftskins.com/"

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting before you generate the world in more options called host privelages.
If enabeled you can give yourself the ability to fly, as well as to be invisible all 
In survival.
    As for the skin.  :(    ???